# dereferencing this causes Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, constructor, segmentation-fault, factory-method

I have the following functions

```
LinearScheme::LinearScheme() {
    cout << " empty constructor" << endl;
}


void LinearScheme::init(
    int tableId,
    std::string &basePath,
    std::vector<size_t> &colElemSizes,
    TupleDescMap &tupleDescMap,
    size_t defaultMaxFragmentSize,
    int numCols,
    BoundBases &bounds,
    std::vector<int> &colsPartitioned ) 
{
    // This linear scheme ignores bounds
    // it could be improved to use colsPartitioned for ordering (TODO)
    cout << "init Linear Scheme " << endl;

    *this = LinearScheme(); //SEGFAULTS HERE

    cout << "after cons here?" << endl;
    // init private fields    
    this->tableId_ = tableId;
    this->basePath_ = basePath;
    this->colElemSizes_ = colElemSizes;
    this->numCols_ = numCols;
    this->tupleDescMap_ = tupleDescMap;
    this->numFragments_ = 0;
    this->defaultMaxFragmentSize_ = defaultMaxFragmentSize;

    // fragmentSizesFilename_ init    
    fragmentSizesFilename_  = basePath_ + boost::lexical_cast <string>(tableId_)
        + "_cs";
    struct stat st;
    // open existing file if exists. Create new otherwise. 
    if (stat(fragmentSizesFilename_.c_str(), &st) == 0) // file existed
        openExisting();
    else
        createNew();
}
```

The reason I am initializing in `init` rather than constructor is because `LinearScheme` extends a `PartitionScheme` (super class with virtual methods) class and another class does that where the constructor is used recursively.

I have a `QuadTree` class which does the same initialization because each `QuadTree` constructor is applied recursively. `*this = QuadTree(bounds, maxSize)`  line in the init function of `QuadTree` class works just fine.

however, this line in the other subclass (LinearScheme) `*this = LinearScheme()` cause a Seg fault.

Any ideas why this might happen?

**EDIT**
Also replacing the line:

```
*this = LinearScheme()
```

with this:

```
*this;
```

or removing it overall gets rid of the Seg Fault ... why?

Comment: Can you post what's going on in the default constructor for LinearScheme()?

Comment: `*this = LinearScheme();` How are your assignment operators defined for class `LinearScheme`? Smells about [rule-of-three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three/4172724#4172724) problem!

Comment: For the case of LinearScheme class, the constructor is empty.

Comment: What about the assignment operator?

Comment: didn't define one for either QuadTree or LinearScheme

Comment: If `*this = LinearScheme;` is called while you're constructing `*this`, well, that's an issue.  If the init() function is called after construction, then you need to show us your assignment operator for LinearScheme or at least tell us what the members are for us to determine if you need one.

Comment: @Highway of Life why did rollback all the edits? and add non-relevant tags.  This really has nothing to do with quadtree at all and you threw away all the formatting i had fixed?

Comment: @Saher can you please show the hierarchy of Scheme and QuadTree classes and why ctors are called recursively?

Comment: because it is a QuadTree , it has 4 members of same type Quadtree which are the childrens of the node

Comment: @Saher "it has 4 members of same type QuadTree" - and these 4 members each are creating 4 members of QuadTree... - looks like infinite recursion, not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"...in the other subclass (LinearScheme) `*this = LinearScheme()`"

"The LinearScheme constructor is empty: `LinearScheme::LinearScheme()`"

if *this is a subclass of LinearMethod, LinearMethod's constructor should already have been called and this line is useless. Besides it calls assignment operator - is it properly defined?

It is better to rely on built-in mechanism of constructing of objects. If you want to avoid code repetition, use C++11 [delegating constructors](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#delegating-ctor) feature. It was specially designed to eliminate "init" methods.

Although, "If there is an infinitely recursive cycle (e.g., constructor C1 delegates to another constructor C2, and C2 also delegates to C1), the behavior is undefined."

So it is up to you to avoid infinite recursion. In your QuadTree you can consider creating nullptr **pointers** to QuadTreeNode in constructor.

Comment: the line is useless as you mentioned. I don't know why it worked with QuadTree. It was calling the constructor twice. Sorry I am completely new to C/C++

Comment: @Saher then start from simple things! Repeat how objects are created and how constructors are called (base classes first, one by one).

Comment: I wish. Unfortunately I just jumped into a project and no time to start from scratch. I learn by experience... getting there

Comment: @Saher Agree with Alex, while many of us learn by experience you can't expect to build a house without building a solid foundation first.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like incorrect `factory method` / `builder` / `deferred construction` usage.  For many of these object creation patterns function that constructs your objects should be a static method because there doesn't yet exist an instance to manipulate.  In others you potentially manipulate an already constructed instance.  In either case if you are actually constructing the object of the class type within the function you should be using new and eventually returning it.

If you are instead going for a `helper` method to assist with initialization then you simply shouldn't be constructing the object within the method itself, and you should just be initializing parts of it within your helper.

A factory pattern example:

```
LinearScheme* LinearScheme::create(...all_your_args....) {

    /* construct the thing we are building only if it 
    *  pass any arguments into him that he can handle directly if you'd like
    */
    LinearScheme *out = new LinearScheme(...);

    /* do whatever else you have to do */
    ....
    return out;
}
```

or this `helper` of sorts that you seem to want

```
/* this time let's just do 'init' on your object */
void LinearScheme::init(....args....) {
    /* possibly check if init has been done already */
    if ( this->init ) return;

    /* proceed to do your initialization stuff
     * but don't construct the 'this' instance since it should already exist
     */

    this->init = true; //so we don't init again if you don't need multiple init's
}
```

Alternatively you can consider the delegate constructor methods in C++11 alex mentions.

However neither of these really strikes me as being the actual problem here.

It's not working because either you probably don't even have a valid `*this` to deference.  This could be because of your usage, or it could be because one failed to create potentially because of infinite recursion.

Here's a wikipedia link on the pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Given what you have said about having to keep passing a dozen arguments around both to parent classes and for your recursive construction, one suggestion you could consider is making a small config struct that you pass along by reference instead of all the discrete parameters. That way you don't have to keep adjusting every signature along the way each time you add / remove another parameter.

The other idea is to seperate entirely the construction of one of your objects from the responsibility of knowing how, where, and when they should be contructed and inserted into your hierarchy.  Hard to say without understanding how you will actually be using `LinearSchme` and what the interface is.

Comment: I agree with you with regards to pattern. I am still confused as to why it might work with a subclass and not with another. Also I am not using a factory pattern this is just to avoid having the constructor have all the properties since in a recursive class I will have to pass all arguments over and over ...

Comment: What do you mean by recursive class?

Comment: QuadTree class I have is implemented recursively where each node of the QuadTree is created using the QuadTree constructor.

Comment: If all of those fields are common to every instance, you probably should have a helper function creating all of them. That said I'm not sure what you are actually buying yourself with that.

Seems like you should have a 'insert' function who takes on the job of traversing to the right spot to call a constructor, instead of making the init/constructor itself deal with this. that's just my 2cents. As to why the other works, as others mentioned there are many reasons.  Have you tried using a debugger at all?